# Passing a self-reference down to an instantiated class

Tags: python, class

I want to pass a self-reference down to an instantiated class (the child should have access to the parent). It works if everything is in one file like this:

```py
class ClassB:
  def __init__(self, name, parent):
    assert isinstance(parent, ClassA)
    self.name = name
    self.parent = parent
    print('my parent is', parent.name)

class ClassA:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.b = ClassB('child', self)

a = ClassA('parent')
```

output is `my parent is parent` as expected

The 2-file version is this:

```py
class ClassB:
  def __init__(self, name, parent):
    from ClassA import ClassA
    assert isinstance(parent, ClassA)
    self.name = name
    self.parent = parent
    print('my parent is', parent.name)
```

and:

```py
from ClassB import ClassB

class ClassA:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.b = ClassB('myName', self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  a = ClassA('parent')
```

output is `assert isinstance(parent, ClassA) AssertionError`

Comment: your file classB.py have no reference of ClassA

Comment: it imports ClassA in the `__init__` function. Otherwise the importing wouldn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the second passes a `__main__.ClassA`, whereas `ClassB` expects a `ClassA.ClassA`. Find a different way of doing this, such as putting `ClassA` in its own module.

Comment: Deleting the **if** doesn't help.

Comment: The `if` has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: I stand corrected. When I put the instanciation of ClassA into _another_ file, it works. Can you explain what the difference is?

Comment: The difference is that the script you run becomes the `__main__` module. This is why its name is `"__main__"`.

Comment: ...and other modules that use THIS module get confused with its name? I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ClassB:
  def __init__(self, name, parent, ClassA):
    assert isinstance(parent, ClassA)
    self.name = name
    self.parent = parent
    print('my parent is', parent.name)
```

and:

```
from ClassB import ClassB

class ClassA:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.b = ClassB('myName', self, ClassA)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  a = ClassA('parent')
```

This works for me, but i don't know if it's what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't see the point in this. If the caller wants to cheat, they can do it in your way. Then it would be better just to omit the `assert` check altogether...